# MVC Core - asp-validation-for and asp-for are generating different ids

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation, tag-helpers

I am trying to use jquery-validation-unobtrusive and it's not showing the error message in the adjacent spans. And I found out that View Engine is rendering different ids for Textbox and Error Span tags.

Is there any way to force those ids naming system to render same ids?

ViewModel:

```
public class RequestJobViewModel
{
    public Models.StudentModel Student { get; set; }
    public Models.JobModel Job { get; set; }

    public decimal StudentPrintingBalance { get; set; }

}
```

Job Model:

```
[Required]
public int NoOfOriginalSides { get; set; }
```

view.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm required">
     <label class="control-label col-md-2" asp-for="@Model.Job.NoOfOriginalSides">No. of Copies:</label>
     <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" maxlength="3" asp-for="@Model.Job.NoOfOriginalSides" />
          <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Job.NoOfOriginalSides" class="text-danger" />
     </div>
</div>
```

But when it is rendering with different ids with **underscore** and **dot**:
`Job_NoOfOriginalSides` and `Job.NoOfOriginalSides`

```
<label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Job_NoOfOriginalSides">No. of Pages:</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input id="Job_NoOfOriginalSides" class="form-control text-right input-validation-error" style="width: 50px;" data-val="true" data-val-required="The NoOfOriginalSides field is required." name="Job.NoOfOriginalSides" value="" type="text">
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Job.NoOfOriginalSides" data-valmsg-replace="true"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `asp-validation-for` does not generate the attribute for the `id`of the input - it generates it for the `name` - `data-valmsg-for="Job.NoOfOriginalSides"` relates to `name="Job.NoOfOriginalSides"` in the `<input />` (and its as its supposed to be) What makes you think you want to change it to use the `id`?

Comment: I thought that validation is linked by using object ids.  That's why I tried to change it.  If they are linking by using the name, the validation labels are not showing for another reason.

Comment: What error are you expecting for what value? And note that a `[Required]` attribute is not really required for an `int` property unless you want to specify the error message to override the default (an `int` cannot be `null` and is required by default)

Comment: My fault... I accidentally removed @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");} line for unknown reason.  It's all working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The error message span is linked to the input control using the name attribute not the Id.
since the letter "." is invalid in the Id, MVC replaces it and any other special character to underscore

Comment: The `.` character is not invalid (at least in HTML5) - its just that it would be read by a jquery selector as signalling the start of a class name